# Java Cannot Format Given Object as Date

Tags: java

I have a string with yyyyMMdd format and I want dd.MM.yyyy

I get this error with my code

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Date

```
String date = "20190226";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");                  
date = sdf.format(date);
```

Any help?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse a `java.util.Date` into a String like this:

```
    String dateStr = "20190226";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    dateStr = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 5):

## java.time

Java 8 and later versions you can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Parsing text.

```
String str = "20190226";
DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(str, inputFormat);
```

Generating text.

```
DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
System.out.println(dateTime.format(outputFormat));
```

> 26.02.2019

Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks @basil-bourque, for editing my answer to make it super neat and informative :)

Comment: May also use `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;` for the input format.